# Finding a specific xml element containt

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Ihave a large xml file and I want to get child element value by giving the parent child element value, I am new in xml file please any help here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<masterController>   <uuid>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</uuid>  
<channels>
    <channel>
      <nodeGroups>
        <nodeGroup>
          <analogNode>
            <typeCode>8</typeCode>
            <id>1</id>
            <sdos>
              <sdo>
                <description>Host ID</description>
                <compareLevel>Ignore</compareLevel>
                <datafield xmlns:xsi="http://www.XXXXX.XXXX/XXXXX/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:type="intField">
                  <description>Host ID</description>
                  <compareLevel>Ignore</compareLevel>
                  <offset>2</offset>
                  <size>1</size>
                  <readonly>true</readonly>
                  <isMappedToPdo>false</isMappedToPdo>
                  <ownerNodeSerial>12102904</ownerNodeSerial>
                  <ownerSdoIndex>3</ownerSdoIndex>
                  <data xsi:type="intData">
                    <value xmlns:xs="http://www.XX.CC/2XXX/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">2</value>
                    <unit></unit>
                    <min>1</min>
                    <max>15</max>
                  </data>
                  <intValue>2</intValue>
                </datafield>
                <index>3</index>
                <totalbytes>3</totalbytes>
              </sdo>
              <sdo>
                <description>Host ID</description>
                <compareLevel>Ignore</compareLevel>
                <datafield xmlns:xsi="http://www.XXXXX.XXXX/XXXXX/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:type="intField">
                  <description>Host ID</description>
                  <compareLevel>Ignore</compareLevel>
                  <offset>2</offset>
                  <size>1</size>
                  <readonly>true</readonly>
                  <isMappedToPdo>false</isMappedToPdo>
                  <ownerNodeSerial>12102905</ownerNodeSerial>
                  <ownerSdoIndex>4</ownerSdoIndex>
                  <data xsi:type="intData">
                    <value xmlns:xs="http://www.XX.CC/2XXX/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">16</value>
                    <unit></unit>
                    <min>1</min>
                    <max>15</max>
                  </data>
                  <intValue>2</intValue>
                </datafield>
                <index>3</index>
                <totalbytes>3</totalbytes>
              </sdo>
            </sdos>
          </analogNode>
        </nodeGroup>
      </nodeGroups>
    </channel>   </channels> </masterController>
```

I' am trying this but am not geting anything:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("sample.xml"));

              IEnumerable<XElement> masterco = from el in root.Elements("sdo") where (from add in   el.Elements("datafield")

                     where
                         (string)add.Element("ownerNodeSerial") == TextBox1.Text &&

                         (string)add.Element("ownerSdoIndex") == TextBox1.Text

                     select add)

                    .Any()
                  select el;
              foreach (XElement el in masterco)
              {

                TextBox3.Text = (string)el.Element("value");
              }
```

I want to get this:

```
 <value xmlns:xs="http://www.XX.CC/2XXX/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">16</value>
```

and be able to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one major error in your query:

You are using `Elements` on `root`, but you are looking for the tag `sdo` which is not a direct child of the root tag. You have to use `Descendants` instead.

Additionally, I think you want to have an `OR` instead of an `AND` regarding the text of `TextBox1`.

Fix it:

```
var masterco = from el in root.Descendants("sdo")
               where (from add in   el.Elements("datafield")
                      where
                          (string)add.Element("ownerNodeSerial") == TextBox1.Text ||
                          (string)add.Element("ownerSdoIndex") == TextBox1.Text
                       select add).Any()
               select el;
```

To actually get the value you want, you should use a different query. There is really no need to select the `sdo` tag at all.

```
var value = root.Descendants("datafield")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Element("ownerNodeSerial") == TextBox1.Text ||
                            (string)x.Element("ownerSdoIndex") == TextBox1.Text)
                .Select(x => (string)x.Element("data").Element("value"))
                .Single();

TextBox3.Text = value;
```

You can see that I am assuming that in the whole XML document only one matching `datafield/data/value` entry exists. I derive that information from the way you update your textbox. This would make no sense if there would be multiple tags - the values would overwrite each other in the text box.

Comment: I tried this on but am getting error say that Sequence contains no elements why is that? plz help me.

Comment: @Clement: Most likely because there is no node where `ownerNodeSerial` and `ownerSdoIndex` are the same as each other and additionally the same as the text in `TextBox1`. Maybe you meant that one of the two should equal the text in the text box? In that case you would need to use `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: @Clement: Additionally, please see update. There is no namespace issue in your case. I was wrong about that and removed it from my answer.

Comment: for some reason I  don't know why is not geting  <value xmlns:xs="http://www.XX.CC/2XXX/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:int">16</value> I want to be able to display that 16 anything plz.

Comment: @Clement: Did you change `&&` to `||`?

Comment: yes I did a miske before i have 2 textboxs one for ownerNodeSerial and other for ownerSdoIndex I can see when i step in the code that is doing what i want but the value is empty.

Comment: @Clement: The code works - I tested it. The problem needs to be something else. Maybe the contents of your textbox don't match exactly or so.

Comment: Thanks Man for sure is my textboxs are wrong you saved me. any Idea of how i can update it?

Comment: @Clement: I have not enough info to answer that. Please post it as a new question with all the necessary info.